# Vector equations with trigonometry

Tags: geometry, functions, trigonometry, vectors

[The question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IXr5J.jpg)

Part a asks to explain why the vector equation for L1 is the written one. I fail to understand why. Any help? It states that L1 passes through the tip and base perimeter of the cone, but shouldn't the Direction Vector be (0j, 1i, 0k ) in that case?

Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  Please use [MathJax](https://www.onemathematicalcat.org/MathJaxDocumentation/TeXSyntax.htm) to format your posts.  To begin with, surround math expressions (including numbers) with `$` signs and use `_` for subscripts.  `$x_1$` comes out as $x_1$.

Answer (score 1):

The question states that the tip is at $(0, 5, 0)$, and that the base perimeter fulfills $x^2 + z^2 = 1$.

(Technically speaking, $x^2 + z^2 = 1$ is really a right circular cylinder of infinite length and radius $1$, axis on the $y$ axis.  Here, they obviously mean that the cone base is a circle of radius $1$ on the $x z$ plane, centered at origin.)

Base perimeter is a circle of radius $1$ centered at origin $(0, 0, 0)$.

If you have a line that passes through $(0, 5, 0)$ in direction $(0, 1, 0)$, it will pass outwards from the tip.  It has already passed through origin, $(0, 0, 0)$.  However, origin is at the center of the base; it is not at the *perimeter* of the base.  (Perimeter is the outer boundary.)

Any line that passes through the tip at $(0, 5, 0)$ and a point on the perimeter of the base, say $(1, 0, 0)$, $(0, 1, 0)$, $(-1, 0, 0)$, or $(0, -1, 0)$, will fulfill the rule.

We can parametrise the points on the perimeter using angle parameter $\theta$, as $(\cos\theta, 0, \sin\theta)$.  (If $\theta = 0$, the point is $(1, 0, 0)$; if $\theta = 90°$, the point is $(0, 1, 0)$; if $\theta = 180°$, the point is $(-1, 0, 0)$, and so on.)

Any line can be parametrised using a real parameter, say $\lambda$, and two points the line passes through, say $\vec{a}$ and $\vec{b}$:
$$\ell = (1 - \lambda) \vec{a} + \lambda \vec{b} = \vec{a} + \lambda (\vec{b} - \vec{a})$$
(This is also the equation for linear interpolation.)  When $\lambda = 0$, $\ell = \vec{a}$.  When $\lambda = 1$, $\ell = \vec{b}$.

Here, $\vec{a} = (0, 5, 0)$ (the tip), and the point on the perimeter $\vec{b} = (\cos\theta, 0, \sin\theta)$, so the equation of the line is
$$\ell = (1 - \lambda)\left[\begin{matrix}0\\5\\0\end{matrix}\right] + \lambda\left[\begin{matrix}\cos\theta\\0\\\sin\theta\end{matrix}\right] = \left[\begin{matrix}0\\5\\0\end{matrix}\right] + \lambda\left[\begin{matrix}\cos\theta\\-5\\\sin\theta\end{matrix}\right]$$